# Plugin conflict error : Admob and Fiebase Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, admob

I need to use **Admob** native plugin and **firebase** but Cordova Build gives error :

```
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseGoogleServices'.
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gm
s.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Many plugins use Firebase and / or Google Play Services libraries & the version must be aligned for all plugins. For example, when one plugin imports version 11.0.1 and another one imports 11.2.0, a gradle build failure will occur which is what seems to have happened here.

To resolve this, you can use the `GMS_VERSION` variable witht he install command to align play-services version across plguins. Uninstall the plugins and re-install them as such :

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --variable GMS_VERSION=11.8.0`

Comment: thanks , i tested this solution but not worked  :
 Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause is that the Admob plugin is pulling in a different version of the Play Services library than Firebase, so you need to align them.

You can do so using [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) and [cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release), for example to align them to v11.8.0:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=11.8.0
cordova plugin add cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release  --variable FIREBASE_VERSION=11.8.0
cordova platform rm android --nosave && cordova platform add android --nosave
cordova build android
```

Though ideally it would be best if you can unpin the library versions and use the latest:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=+
cordova plugin add cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release  --variable FIREBASE_VERSION=+
cordova platform rm android --nosave && cordova platform add android --nosave
cordova build android
```

Comment: Please list the exact plugins and plugin versions in your project: `cordova plugin ls`